# How can I extract the value of a specific field from a MongoDB collection and group them in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the documents like:

```
{
   person1:"x",
   person2:"a",
   relation:"friend"
},
{
 person1:"x",
   person2:"b",
   relation:"friend"
},
{  
    person1:"x",
   person2:"c",
   relation:"friend"
}
```

i want to get the field `person2` as an array of Strings which have `person1 : "x"` and `relation:"friend"`.

something like `{ friendList:["a", "b", "c" ] }` .

Can Anyone help me please?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {              // Use $match operator to match the values of person1 and relation fields.
      $expr: {
        $and: [            // Use $and operator to AND the truth values of both the equalities.
          {
            $eq: [         // Check the equality of person1 field to 'x'.
              "$person1",
              "x"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [         // Check the equality of relation field to 'friend'.
              "$relation",
              "friend"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {              // Group the documents by person1 field.
      _id: "$person1",
      friendList: {
        $push: "$person2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      person1: "$_id",     // Project the _id field as person1 field.
      friendList: 1,
      _id: 0               // Don't display _id field anymore.
    }
  }
])
```

This will produce the following output based on the given collection in the OP:

```
[
  {
    "friendList": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ],
    "person1": "x"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate with these pipelines:

```
aggregate([
    {
        $match: {                 // This pipeline filters your documents
            person1: 'x'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {                  // This pipeline groups your documents
            _id: '$person1',       // _id is required to be able to group the docs
            friendList: {
                $push: '$person2'. // $push will push your every person2 value to friendsList
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { // Projection
            _id: 0
        }
    }

])
```